# print htm file in c# without header and footer

Tags: html, file, printing

I need to print html files that I created in c# code. I have done  it by a process:

```
 System.IO.File.WriteAllText("1.html",printHtml,Encoding.UTF8);
    Process printjob = new Process();
    printjob.StartInfo.FileName = "1.html";
    printjob.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
    printjob.StartInfo.Verb = "print";
    printjob.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    printjob.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    printjob.Start();
```

the printed document contains default header(Page 1of X) and default footer(file url).how can I print html file without this header and footer?

Answer (score 0):

If found the solution, I saved the html file with ".doc" extension and then printed the doc file.
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText("1.html", printHtml, Encoding.UTF8);
    Process printjob = new Process();
    printjob.StartInfo.FileName = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(
    System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase) + "\1.html"
    printjob.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
    printjob.StartInfo.Verb = "print";
    printjob.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    printjob.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    printjob.Start();